# Failure attaching SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I developed an application in ASP.net 4.0 in visual studio 2010, connected with a SQL Server 2008 database. I copied my ASP.net application to a webserver IIS 6.0 with a SQL Server 2005 EXPRESS, OS Windows 2003 werver.
When I try to browse my website I get the following error:

> The database 'C:\TELEFOON\TELEFOON\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 611 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>
> Could not open new database 'C:\TELEFOON\TELEFOON\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Telefoon\Telefoon\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I do understand the problem but is there a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you created the database on SQL Server 2008 R2, and are trying to open it on SQL Server 2008 (or SQL Server 2005? I forget internal database version numbers). You can't go backwards like this; you'll need to either install SQL Server 2008 R2 to restore the database directly, or you'll need to create an empty database and copy the table/structure using the SSMS wizards (like import/export data, which DOES work between versions in spite of O.D's comments to the contrary, or the generate scripts option) or 3rd party tools. I blogged about some 3rd party tools here:

http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

---

This comment was more about the 2008 R2 -> 2008 problem:

Every time this happens I curse Microsoft for their absolutely moronic decision to name a full release of SQL Server "R2" - I blogged about this here, since every day there seems to be confusion that 2008 and 2008 R2 are the "same release" or that 2008 R2 is just a service pack:

https://sqlblog.org/2011/02/09/is-sql-server-2008-r2-a-full-release-of-sql-server

Comment: @O.D why not? I just tried the "Export Data" wizard to move a table and its data from 2008 -> 2005 and it worked fine. You can also use the generate scripts wizard, for example, to generate a script (including both schema and data) and they even have options in Management Studio to specify a specific down-level target (so you don't include options that aren't possible in lower versions). Can you explain what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: With the scripts it works for small databases but i couldnt export import a database with 4 tables and very little data using the wizzard.

Comment: @O.D so why are you convinced that had anything to do with versions?

Comment: cause it works between both 2008 <->2008, nd the same between 2005<->2005 but as soon as i try this between different versions on the SQLServer it doesnt work.

Comment: @O.D and since I have told you that 2008 -> 2005 works fine, is it possible that yours is breaking due to other factors, not just version? Blindly stating that import/export doesn't work between versions is false and misleading. It's actually one of the primary purposes of that wizard.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just to say version 611 is 2005, 655 is 2008 :-)

Comment: @Bridge ok well some of my rant is still relevant because people with 2008 R2 -> 2008 problems are more common, and will become more so, and may still come across this question. :-)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: please read what microsoft states here: Backups that are created by more recent version of SQL Server cannot be restored in earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @O.D I know that, that is the reason for this question and my answer that suggests workarounds to a backup/restore. Do you think the export data wizard creates a database backup?

Comment: @O.D - Backups and scripts for a database are two **completely** different things

Comment: @O.D: unless you're confusing MySQL "backups" with SQL Server. Quite different products and techniques around ETL and backup/restores

Comment: @O.D. In general, it's best to check your references before telling a Microsoft SQL Server MVP that they are wrong...

Comment: @Lamak ASAIK both can be used to copy Database from one server to another no? and this is the issue in this question.

Comment: @JNK Please spare me your lectures, checking your references is allways good, MVP or not is irrelevant here, but just to mention i didnt say he is wrong i mentioned my experience in an issue beeign handeled in this question. anyway we are still human beeing and we make mistakes even after checking references.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand ur right, my mistake, what didnt work for me was the backup database option between two different DB-Versions and not the export import data. in general stil the version incompatibility is the issue. i tried to edit my comment from export data to backup database but it doesnt seem to work. and i give +1 for the long disscussion.

Comment: @O.D I think the primary objection is to your first comment, which implies the wizards don't work. Future readers may read that comment and believe you. I suggest you voluntarily delete it. I think your subsequent comments adequately cover what it was that really didn't work in your sprecific scenario, without having to cast such overwhelming doubt on the wizards in general.

Comment: Thanks guys, i just removed all the sql server installations and started from beginning with succes!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following it may help:

- Select your database in the SSMS Wizard
- right-click then selectTasks and Generate Scripts.
- enable all options in the dialogbox including script data and "Script
  for SQL Server 2005".
- Try to run  the scripts on your SQL Server 2005.

If this doesnt help i can recommend you [OmegaSync](http://www.spectralcore.com/omegasync/)