# Downgrade mdf file from 661 to 655

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I created and database in sql server 2008. I took the mdf and ldf files to Visual Studio 2010 project and tried to connect to that db with entity-framework. and got the following message:

[image]

I cannot reinstall or upgrade the software on the specific computer.
So is there any way to downgrade the version of the mdf and ldf files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failure attaching SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778220/failure-attaching-sql-server-2008-database-to-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot downgrade, you will need to move the schema and data another way if you can't install the right version. This recent question is essentially the same:

[Failure attaching SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778220/failure-attaching-sql-server-2008-database-to-sql-server-2005/)

Essentially you can use the Generate Scripts tool or the Export Data wizard to get your destination database to look like the source. You will not be able attach your MDF file.

And this blog post shows some 3rd party tools that can help with this:

http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to install the same or newer version of SqlServer.
There is no known way to downgrade an MDF file.

Links

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/16/sql-server-downgrade-database-to-previous-version/

Perhaps, if you have access to the SqlServer 2008, you could use the command
"Tasks" -> "Create Scripts" to start the wizard to create a script with schema and data.
On the options page there is the button 'Advanced' where you can select the syntax version of SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

The way that I found that worked was to export the database and stored procedures from the original database. Then upload them into the second database(second computer).

Firstly export the DB content (data) - I used SQL server export data wizard. on the database you wish to export from right click then choose tasks, then export data. Follow the instructions and save in whichever format is best for you - I used excel for the data.

then to export the stored procedures rightclick the database name again. choose tasks and this time choose generate scripts. again follow the instructions of the wizard.

To import the data simply go to the second computer and right click the database you wish to import the data into. again tasks > import data. Follow the instructions to import all of the data from the database.

Finally to import the stored procedures, I opened up a new stored procedures command and dragged and dropped the script file that I had previously saved them in and dropped it into this window. The new stored procedure window filled with the entire list of my stored procedures. 
Finally change the name of the database name that will be used by the SP ( if this  is different from the original DB name). (This is the first line USE [DBName].
then simply execute and the SP's will be fully restored.

This has helped me get my entire database up and running again very quickly.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

U can open it on another pic and then publish it to sql script with or without data then create database on target PC using sqlcmd or anything. Then run sql script...